# how to make a common linker for keil and IAR

Tags: linker, keil, iar

I am trying to convert my project from keil MDK-ARM to IAR toolchain.
I want to use one linker file for both.
Is that possible?
If yes, Does anyone have a template that may help me do this?

Comment: Do you mean the linker configuration file (icf in IAR). I don't know what format Keil uses, but typically different compilers tend to use different linker configuration file formats. You have to read manual of each one to see what the format is and possibly write both by hand.

Comment: For keik is (sct or lin). yes I know that but I was wandering if they integreted a common format such as .ld linker?